# How to store exceptions or errors in database in symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, symfony4

Is there a way, where I can store all exceptions or errors into database which has occurred in Symfony 4 application? I just started learning Symfony. Please let me know if there is anyway to store these errors and exceptions into the database.

Thanks..

Comment: Create an exception listener. Inject Repository into it and save the error message. Now, you need to do research and development on that instructions. Start from [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/symfony) fro example.

Comment: "Build a man a fire, and he'll be warm for a day. Set a man on fire, and he'll be warm for the rest of his life." so my instructions above sets you on fire!